# Why is the source code between listings indented and numbered wrong?

Tags: beamer, listings, indentation

Here is my code and output. We can see that the number and indent of the inner loop is wrong.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{dolphin}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
  \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape, family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  frame=single,
  captionpos=b,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Loop-unrolled, register-blocked code}
  \begin{lstlisting}
  void sparse_mvm_bcsr_2x3(int M, int n,
    const double* Aval, const int* Aind, const int* Aptr,
    const double* x, double* y) 
  {
    int I;
    for(I = 0; I < M; I++, y += 2) {
      register double y0 = y[0], y1 = y[1];
      int jj;
      for(jj = Aptr[I]; jj < Aptr[I + 1]; jj++, Aval += 6) 
      {
    int j = Aind[jj];
    register double x0 = x[j], x1 = x[j + 1], x2 = x[j + 2];
    y0 += Aval[0] * x0; y1 += Aval[3] * x0;
    y0 += Aval[1] * x1; y1 += Aval[4] * x1;
    y0 += Aval[2] * x2; y1 += Aval[5] * x2;
      }
      y[0] = y0; y[1] = y1;
    }
  }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue about the spacing. It gives me the right spacing.

Comment: @karlkoeller: It is weird. I only got the warning:|| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
|| LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences.

Comment: @karlkoeller: After add \let\Tiny\tiny, I still get the same output.

Comment: As I said in a previous question, try updating your TeX distribution.

Comment: @karlkoeller: OK, I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue with the hidden numbers, add the following options to your `\lstset`

```
  framexleftmargin=-10pt,
  numbersep=-2pt,
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
  \usecolortheme{dolphin}
  \usecolortheme{rose}
  \setbeamerfont*{title}{shape=\itshape, family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  frame=single,
  framexleftmargin=-10pt,
  numbersep=-2pt,
  captionpos=b,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Loop-unrolled, register-blocked code}
  \begin{lstlisting}
  void sparse_mvm_bcsr_2x3(int M, int n,
    const double* Aval, const int* Aind, const int* Aptr,
    const double* x, double* y)
  {
    int I;
    for(I = 0; I < M; I++, y += 2) {
      register double y0 = y[0], y1 = y[1];
      int jj;
      for(jj = Aptr[I]; jj < Aptr[I + 1]; jj++, Aval += 6)
      {
    int j = Aind[jj];
    register double x0 = x[j], x1 = x[j + 1], x2 = x[j + 2];
    y0 += Aval[0] * x0; y1 += Aval[3] * x0;
    y0 += Aval[1] * x1; y1 += Aval[4] * x1;
    y0 += Aval[2] * x2; y1 += Aval[5] * x2;
      }
      y[0] = y0; y[1] = y1;
    }
  }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]